# Create library in j2me

Tags: java-me

I am a beginner in j2me.I want to create a **library(jar)** in j2me. Could anyone guide me regarding the same.

Comment: Which library you want to create?

Comment: I guess this platform is not for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simple steps you have to follow.

1. Create New Project Without any midlet.
2. Create your classes which you want in library.
3. Compile all classes.
4. Right click on Project & Select Properties.
5. Click on creating Jar & Give name for Jar & Jad
6. Now Clean & Build Your Project.
7. Your Library ready to use in jar file.

Comment: How do i include the j2me libraries in a java project? I am using java_me_sdk3.0.5.

Comment: Right Click on Project->Select Build-> Click on Libraries-> Click on Add Jar button on right side->Window will be open and select your jar->that set.

Comment: Thanks Sajid.. I wanted to add the jsr170.jar,cldc1.1.jar and midp jars. Thats what i was confused with. I was under an impression that  i would be having a single bundled j2me jar which i could add in the project.