# Jar creation in j2me

Tags: java-me, executable-jar

I developed an application in j2me,created a jar for that application. Now I want this jar to be used in another application. I imported that jar in my first application, but when I try to import that jar in my class (code) (for example:`import.org`), that jar file is not showing as option. Is there anything to be done when creating a jar which is to be used in another project?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse? Netbeans?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,it works fine:

> 1. Create New Project Without any midlet.
> 2. Create your classes which you want in library.
> 3. Compile all classes.
> 4. Right click on Project & Select Properties.
> 5. Click on creating Jar & Give name for Jar & Jad
> 6. Now Clean & Build Your Project.
> 7. Your Library ready to use in jar file.

See [Create library in j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495340/create-library-in-j2me/9495719#9495719).